# Getting count to work for playa field within Matrix

Tags: matrix, playa, count

I've got a page which is displaying information based on a playa entry within a matrix field, when using the matrix :search parameter, this works as intended. But I need to be able to use the {count} tag. The problem is that the image thumbnails and information for each matching entry are simply looping, so the {count} just displays 1 for each of the returned results. I would like them to be 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. I have tried all the other Matrix tags, such as {row_count}, {total_rows}, {field_row_index} etc. but none of these do the job.

If any one could offer any guidance, or other ways round this, I'd be grateful. Thanks.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel='profile-entry' disable="member_data|pagination|categories" orderby="surname" sort="asc" dynamic="no"}
{services_new search:parent="{segment_3}"}<!-- Matrix Entry, 'parent' is the Playa column within it-->
    <!-- Playa 'related' fields that match segment_3-->
    <a href="{site_url}our-people/{url_title}" class="{if {count} == 1}col4 firstfour firstthree firsttwo {/if}{if {count} == 2}col4{/if}{if {count} == 3}col4 firsttwo{/if}">
        <img src="{profile-portrait}" alt="{title} Profile Picture" width="100%" />
        <h3>{title}</h3>
        <h3 class="title">{profile-position}</h3>
    </a>
{/services_new}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to get the count of multiple playa entries for each matrix row? If so, you should be able to do something like the following, setting a different namespace prefix for matrix and playa to separate their tags:

```
{your_matrix_field_name var_prefix="mx"}
    Matrix row {mx:row_count} of {mx:total_rows} total rows.<br>

    {mx:your_playa_column_name var_prefix="pl"} {!-- Playa column --}
        Playa entry "{pl:title}" with count of {pl:count}.<br>
    {/mx:your_playa_column_name}

{/your_matrix_field_name}
```

UPDATE:
Based on your code example it looks like you're counting Matrix rows, so try:

```
class="{if {row_count} == 1}classnames {/if} 
or
{if {row_count} == 1}class="classnames"{/if}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response.
I'm trying to use the {count} tag to switch class based on conditionals (I have already exhausted trying to use the {switch} tag.) I have tried your solution but I'm afraid this doesn't seem to be the answer. I have included my code with the original post above.

Comment: I've updated the post - since you're counting Matrix rows {row_count} is what you want.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the update solution.
Using {row_count} is returning a value of 1 for each entry that appears, even if there are 5 displayed. Rather than counting them 1,2,3,4,5 ??

Comment: Have you tried simplifying your example down to just the absolute minimum for testing?

Comment: To a point, yes. If I take out all the if conditionals, and restrict the display to one entry field, say 'title'. even without all the extra html, if i put {title}(row_count} it still displays 1 for each entry on screen. I wondered if it might be because of the search:parent parameter, but this is necessary for the correct results to be displayed.